# Using REST API in Java for acessing FRED (is a tool for automatically producing RDF/OWL)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, nlp

I have been trying to use REST API in Java for the webservice [FRED](http://wit.istc.cnr.it/stlab-tools/fred/?text=Miles%20Davis%20was%20an%20american%20jazz%20musician.) an NLP tool. Below is my code which I have been trying to run.

```
    package lcr;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class TestGet{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            Client client = Client.create();

            WebResource webResource = client
                    .resource("http://wit.istc.cnr.it/stlab-tools/fred/");

            ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("Miles Davis was an american jazz musician"
                    , "application/rdf+xml")
                    .get(ClientResponse.class);

            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response.getStatus());
            }

            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            System.out.println(output);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

and the output:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400
    at lcr.TestGet.main(TestGet.java:22)
```

I have tried to lookup for the error itself (400 = Bad Request), but seem not to understand what it means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the service incorrectly. Try:

```java
ClientResponse response = webResource.queryParam("text", "Miles Davis was an american jazz musician").accept("application/rdf+xml").get(ClientResponse.class);
```

Comment: Thank you, I checked it again with the said modifications and its working now.